Flame Sensor Supply Voltage Range
I have this flame sensor module which I am going to use for a project. Upon closer inspection, I can see that the maximum supply voltage of the LM393 comparator IC used is 30V according to this datasheet. But in the website of the sensor module, the maximum supply voltage of the module is given as 5V. So if the IC can handle much more voltage than 5V, what other component on the module limits the maximum voltage to 5V. Is it the maximum reverse breakdown voltage of the photodiode? The maximum reverse voltage hasn't been mentioned in the website of the module, but it is there in the actual photodiode page in the same website. Or the limitation is because of some other factors? The schematic of the sensor is given below.

Electroduino - IR Infrared Flame Sensor Module | How Fire Sensor Works https://www.electroduino.com/ir-infrared-flame-sensor-module/

I've have some TETP4000 photo transistors, which have a max voltage of 6 V. They are clear case though, not IR filtered as the pic in your link shows. But the possibility is clear. The design might limit the voltage to 5 V, so resistor ratios, or bias currents. And as jstola asked, please put the schematic in your post, don't leave a link to it lying around in comments, which are volatile.

Try to make your post understandable without having to follow links. You haven't mentioned the make and model in your question and we have to follow three links in the question to understand it. Now you've added another in the comments. (You were asked to add it to the question.) Make it easy for people to help you.

@Transistor There is no specific model number for this component. I have added the link to the websites of the components and the datasheet so that others can get some crucial information from them. Regarding adding links to the comments, I have removed it and added the image to the post. So now it'll be better if you can clarify my doubts regarding the sensor.

Without a datasheet for the photodiode it is difficult to say. The obvious problems are that R1 and R3 would have to be increased and the top of VR1 would need to be reduced to 5 V using a 50k series resistor so that the pot didn't become ridiculously sensitive as you'd be only using 1/6th of its span.

The other components like the photodiode, the LEDs can handle less. Moreover, the circuit is designed to be directly connected to Arduino's digital pin. That means, if you give the mentioned input, the output voltage will be  5V which you can connect directly to the Arduino. If you are planning to design an Arduino compatible flame sensor, you can check this 8-channel sensor: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/SENTINEL_Flame_Sensor_8_channel_kit_Arduino.html
